# Cannot generate entities from existing MySQL db tables using Dali JPA Tools

Tags: eclipse-plugin, dali

Fairly new to Java, Eclipse and JPA. I was steered toward using JPA for CRUD database application development. As I have seen posted in earlier messages (more than 5 years old) I also am not able to create entities from an existing database using the JPA tool, because a list of schemas, and their corresponding tables, do not show up in the dropdown list box in the Entity Creation dialog under JPA tools. They also do not show up in the Data Source Explorer (although that windows shows schemas, but devoid of tables).

I read in older posts that you have to explicitly name the database/schema in your URL string for the Dali JPA tools to actually work. I attempted that, here are the Connection details below related to a schema (database) called game_world in a MySQL database.

Eclipse: Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)
Build id: 20190314-1200

JPA: 2.1
Configuration: Basic JPA Configuration

CONNECTION CONFIGURATION
Database: game_world (tried this and mysql)
URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/game_world (also tried it without game_world)

driver class in Driver Definition: I tried the following classes
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
driver version: 8.0.16

Note: I can ping the database successfully from the Connection Dialog Box, and both my and the default schemas that came with MySQL show up in Data Source Explorer, but they are devoid of any tables, views, etc. And as mentioned, nothing gets populated in the schema dropdown in the RPA Generate Entity from Tables Tool window.

I also installed DBeaver plug-in after this, just to see if another interface tool could see the DB tables, and it had no issues listing all the tables. DBeaver used the above Connection to do that.

If DBeaver is seeing the tables doesn't that mean that DTP plug-in is fine and it's a Dali issue?  But that can't be, right?  Or Data Source Explorer window would also be seeing the tables, and it isn't.

Comment: Update on testing - I finally got frustrated enough to install Postgres and test this with Eclipse Dali plugin.  Worked like a charm so far.  So the choice now is between the work of migrating the database to Postgres or troubleshoot MySQL with Dali JPA in Eclipse.

Comment: Dali is built on top of the Eclipse Data Tools Platform (DTP), which is the plugin that  provides the Data Source Explorer. If the Data Source Explorer does not display any tables, that means the core DTP plugin is not successfully retrieving the appropriate MySQL metadata. And that means Dali will not be able to detect any tables either, as Dali relies on the the core DTP plugin to retrieve the metadata. You might see if there are any DTP-specific posts concerning problems with MySQL. [I am not surprised there might be problems with MySQL, as that particular DTP extension is atypical.]

Comment: Thank you, I suppose this can be closed out then given the most likely issue.  It's really the DTP plugin that preventing the access.  Postgres still working well in this setup, I will most likely abandon MySQL to avoid the troubleshooting effort.